# Error message while connecting to EC2 instance via Cygwin

Tags: ssh, dns, cygwin, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect my EC2 instance using the directions my instructor provided below:

"To connect to EC2 via Cygwin on Windows, you need to handle two key idiosyncrasies. First, the Windows directory structure sits off to the side from where Cygwin lives, so you need to address files in /cygdrive/c or cygdrive/d to access files on the C:\ and D:\ drives, such as the .pem file you just downloaded. Second, Cygwin has a permissions bug which requires an extra command to fix. You will thus need to execute the following commands, replacing JohnSmith, cs184-stanford-edu.pem and ec2-50-19-140-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com with your own variables."

```
$ cd ~  
$ cp /cygdrive/c/Users/JohnSmith/Downloads/cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem .  
$ chgrp Users cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem  
$ chmod 0400 cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem  
$ ssh -i cs184-john-stanford-edu.pem \  
ubuntu@ec2-50-19-140-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I run those commands with my own specific key and variables, all of them work until I input the ssh command with my own DNS. I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyggssapi-3.dll: cannot open  
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed the instructions exactly after launching my instance. I saved my .pem file to a folder in my computer. My DNS is in the format ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, which is slightly different from the one in the instructions, but I feel like it shouldn't make a difference. I'm using the Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type AMI and a t2.micro instance type.

Any suggestions for what I need to change?

Comment: Looks like an incomplete cygwin install.  Following the steps in this question may help: http://superuser.com/questions/123446/cygwin-library-load-error

Comment: Thanks I reinstalled and made sure to include all the packages that I thought were overkill before. It worked this time.